# In bootstrap-vue project method of included are not triggered

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, dom-events, bootstrap-vue

In my vue/cli 4/vuex / bootstrap-vue project app I have big page of ads listings with modal dialogs defined
and I want to move dialogs to separate *.vue file, as these dialogs would be used in other pages too
To communicate when dialog must be opened I emit events, and these events are not triggered in my separate *.vue file. 
In src/views/ads/AdsListing.vue I define:

```
<template>

    <b-card class="frontend_listing_container">
        ...
        <ads-modal></ads-modal>
    </b-card>

</template>

<script>

    import Vue from 'vue'
    import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
    Vue.use(VueResource)

    import {bus} from '@/main'
    import appMixin from '@/appMixin';

    ...
    Vue.component('ads-modal', require('../ads/AdsModal.vue').default);

    export default {
        data() {

        ...
        methods: {
            runEditAdModal(ed_id) {
                console.log('runEditAdModal ed_id::')
                console.log(ed_id)  // IN THE CONSOLE I SEE THIS method is called

                console.log('+++ runEditAdModalbus::')
                console.log(bus) // AND VALID BUS OBJECT

                bus.$emit('showEditAdModal', ed_id)
            }
```

In src/views/ads/AdsModal.vue I try to catch event in component events :

```
<script>

    import Vue from 'vue'
    import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

    ...
    import {bus} from '@/main'
    import appMixin from '@/appMixin';

    ...

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
            ...
            }
        },

        name: 'adsModal',

        created() {
            alert( 'src/views/ads/AdsModal.vue CREATED::' ) // I DO NOT SEE THIS ALERT POPUP

        }, // created() {

        mounted() {
            alert( 'src/views/ads/AdsModal.vue MOUNTED::' )  // I DO NOT SEE THIS ALERT POPUP
            bus.$on('showEditAdModal', (ed_id) => {
                console.log('showEditAdModalged ed_id::')
                console.log(ed_id)
                ...
            }) // bus.$on('page_changed', (from, to) => {
        }, // mounted() {
```

As events are not triggered, showEditAdModal event is not cathced. 
What is wrong and how to fix it ?

```
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.1.0",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.27",
"vue": "^2.6.10",
"vue-date-pick": "^1.2.1",
```

**UPDATED # 1:**
a) with

```
Vue.component('ads-modal', require('../ads/AdsModal.vue'));
```

I got warning :

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <AdsModal>
       <AdsListingPage>
         <HomePage> at src/views/Home.vue
           <AppContainer> at src/App.vue
             <Root>
```

But created/mounted events are not triggered;

b) with line

```
   Vue.component('ads-modal', () => import('../ads/AdsModal.vue'))
```

no warning and created/mounted events are not triggered anyway.

c) I tried to move import into src/main.js (commenting it in my src/views/ads/AdsListing.vue) and the same :
created/mounted events are not triggered and I do not know how to trigger methods in AdsModal.vue.

Comment: It maybe that your component is not registered correctly.  Try changing your require to `require('../ads/AdsModal.vue')` (without the `.default`, unless you have other named exports in your `AdsModal.vue` file). Or switch to dynamic `import()`: `Vue.component('ads-modal', () => import('../ads/AdsModal.vue'))`

Comment: Please look at UPDATED # 1

Comment: What about just importing the component is the normal way (no require): `import AdsModal from '../ads/AdsModal.vue'` and then register the component in your page/app `export default { ... components: { 'ads-modal': AdsModal }, ...}`

Comment: I tried the way you proposed : the same result

Comment: Does the child component render any markup?

Comment: Yes, at top of this fiel I have <template>
    <div>
           <h1>src/views/ads/AdsModal.vue</h1>
and this h1 title  I see on the page

Comment: I moved all modal definitions and js methods into main app  container App.vue it it works ok. but that does not seem best decision. I am afraid that App.vue could be too big...